# MariaDB procedure and functions privileges

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

Good day everyone, i cant figure out what to do anymore. I've imported my database to the server remotely.

So here is my procedure, i have a definer db_hrmis@127.0.0.1:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`db_hrmis`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `proce_give_employee_leave_credits`()
BEGIN
UPDATE inf_employee_leaves lv SET lv.earnings = (lv.leaveMinutesPerMonth + lv.earnings), lv.allowedLeaveInMinutes = ((lv.noOfDays - (CONVERT((lv.earnings/480), DECIMAL(10,2)))) * 480), lv.noOfDays = CONVERT((lv.allowedLeaveInMinutes / 480), DECIMAL(10,2)) WHERE MONTH(lv.lastUpdated) <> MONTH(CURDATE());
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

since im accessing it remotely i've also created a database user from my server(e.g. db_hrmis@myipaddress).
The problem is after importing the procedures the definers changed and i cant alter my procedure, and when i try to export it mysql dump shows only like this

```
DELIMITER //
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

empty structure, i tried granting permissions(execute, create routine, alter routine) but nothing seems to work.

here is a screenshot of its current state.
[image]

as you can see, the definers does not state 127.0.0.1 and i have "You have no privilege to this routine" problem, if its a privilege problem, what privilege should i grant to the user?

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because mysql user has no execute privilege on that particular sp on  your_db.table.

Can you please Post the output of `# mysql> show grants for <your user>;`

Or else you may confirm this by running procedure after granting full privilege for that particular user on all databases.

```
# mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'host';
# mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: user db_hrmis@127.0.0.1 and db_hrmis@ipaddress has same grants,
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO db_hrmis@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'passwordhere';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_hrmis.* TO db_hrmis@ipaddress;

Comment: The CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EXECUTE, and GRANT privileges apply to stored routines (functions and procedures).  
{GRANT CREATE ROUTINE ON mydb.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO 'someuser'@'somehost'; }  these would be enough to run sp on specific db.

Comment: tried GRANT EXECUTE bro, but still, 'no privileges'

Comment: Its just for confirmation, have you given privilege for mysql user `db_hrmis@127.0.0.1` or `db_hrmis@192.168.100.106` [I assume this is client ip]..?? To narrow down mysql server need to have `'db_hrmis'@'%'` or `'db_hrmis@'client_ip'` user with execute privilege to run your SP remotely.

Comment: i have 'db_hrmis'@'client_ip', i already solved it dude, created with '%' and set grant privileges, thanks also for the help.